# Fixed position element is not actually being fixed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Chrome has started doing something very strange with a fixed position element. Basically it's still scrolling with the page even though it's set as fixed. It would be easiest to explain just by linking to the live site.

http://new.safetylineloneworker.com/?page_id=9

If you look at it in firefox, or hell, even IE the "Block 1 Block 2 Block 3" text acts just as it should, sticking to the top of the screen once you scroll it there until you hit the 'release point' further down.

Look at it in Chrome, and not only does it jump to its fixed position earlier than it should, but it also just...scrolls, even though it is clearly set to be fixed position. It really is one of the most bizarre things I have ever seen.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "Block 1 Block 2 Block 3" in your page, and some image assets seem to be 404ing.

Comment: which element in your page has position: fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you are using transforms. That's what's causing the problem.

Take a look at the spec: [The Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering)

> Specifying a value other than ‘none’ for the ‘transform’ property
>   establishes a new local coordinate system at the element that it is
>   applied to.

So the element with fixed positioning will become relative to the element with the transform - not the viewport

Look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Hj6Wk/5/) in a webkit browser to see this in action

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>

.wpr
{
    width: 200px;
    height:1000px;
    background: pink;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.fixed
{
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: fixed;    
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Chrome (and Safari, but Chrome is the focus of this question).

I haven't found an open issue for this bug; you should submit a report to [Chromium Issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).