# Issue with fixed elements when using transform:translate on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a weird problem with fixed elements with translated parents, I'll try to explain it as much as I can.

My JsFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/94qaueuL/1/

Basically, I have a green header that should appear when the page is scrolled into the second `<section>`. I also have some fancy content underneath the whole `#site-wrap`. If you click the `<section>`, it will put `transform:translate(-50%, 0)` into `#site-wrap`.

The problem is, when `#site-wrap` is translated, the header gets kind of messed up. It doesnt follow the `position:fixed` anymore.

Any Idea how I can fix this?

I hope Im making sense here...

EDIT - Oh and the header script thing where it should appear when scrolled doesnt even matter. It still gets messed when i translate the parent.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578427/fixed-position-element-is-not-actually-being-fixed-in-chrome/19578720#19578720) ..I'd suggest using left/right postioning instead of translate in this case

Comment: @Danield Yea, that was my first option, the transitions didnt work though, so thats another problem. lol.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you are using transforms.

Take a look at the spec regarding [The Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering)

> Specifying a value other than ‘none’ for the ‘transform’ property
>   establishes a new local coordinate system at the element that it is
>   applied to.

So the element with fixed positioning will become relative to the element with the transform - not the viewport

To fix this I'd suggest using left/right positioning instead of transforms.

Comment: I see. But for some reason, having `left:-400px` on the addClass doesnt do the transition effects, any reason why that happens?

Comment: you know what, nevermind that, I realized i didint set the initial left. Sorry about that, I just havent had sleep. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your example you just need to put #header outside #site-wrap.